# SqlConnection.OpenAsync doesn't work on .net 4.5^

Tags: ado.net

I have a method with a signature like this:

```
internal async static Task<string> Get()
{
   var SqlCon = await InitializeConnection();
   return "Foo";
}
```

I call this method like this:

```
var x = Get().Result;
```

Description of other method

```
internal async static Task<SqlConnection> InitializeConnection()
{
        SqlConnection sc;
        sc = new SqlConnection();            
        sc.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\MSSQL;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True;Async=True";                                  
         await sc.OpenAsync();//on this line the program long waits and doesn't connect

        return sc;
    }
```

I checked with different correct lines of connection without use of asynchrony and everything worked. How to fix it ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably causing a deadlock by using `Result`. You should use `await` instead.

I explain this [deadlock in detail on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). In essence, there are many contexts (such as UI or ASP.NET contexts) that only permit a single thread to execute at a time. By default, `await` will capture a context and resume the rest of the `async` method in that context. So, by (synchronously) blocking a thread in that context by calling `Result`, you are preventing the `async` method from completing.

Comment: I specified "await Get ()", but now as a result I receive the line "System.Threading.Tasks.Task ' 1 [System.String]".

Comment: Sounds like you're using MVC 3? On ASP.NET, you must use .NET 4.5 and set your `targetFramework` to 4.5 in your web.config.